# creating and accessing loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a loop of JSON files to read into an object and bind them automatically

I'm using 22 URL's of JSON files and read them in a loop so that I need not write those 22 objects in the rbind function like rbind(obj1, obj2,....obj22). I have written a function extractdata() that pulls the data from JSON into data frame

```
ds1_1 <-extractdata("http://open.statswales.gov.wales/en-gb/dataset/hlth1308")

ds1_2 <- extractdata("http://open.statswales.gov.wales/en-gb/dataset/hlth1308?%24skiptoken=1!24!MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMTAwMA--%7c1!0!%7c1000%7cc22fdf38fca142e7bf4b7efb37826cab")
```

and so on 22 URL's.

Looking for something like:

```
ds1 <- for(i in 0:22){
                      read 22 files
                      }
  rbind(all these files)
return(final one)
```

Comment: Could you add what packages you're using? Or add what `extractdata` looks like?

Comment: Sure: here is the function:
extractdata <- function(link){ #input link
  
  jsonlink <- rjson::fromJSON(file = link) #read the data from JSON file
  jsonlink <- jsonlink[[2]]
  maindata <- data.frame(jsonlink[[1]], stringsAsFactors = F)#read thedata as dataframe
  for(i in 2:length(jsonlink)) #from 0 to the length of the file
    maindata <- rbind(maindata, jsonlink[[i]]) #bind all the data
    return(maindata) #return the final dataset.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `r-base` functions only, try with `lapply` and `do.call`:

```
URLs <- c("Url1",...,"Urln")
ldata <- lapply(URLs, extractdata)
alld_data <- do.call("rbind",ldata)
```

This should make the job.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store all your urls in a vector, say `urls`. Once you have that, you can define a new function using *extractdata* as:

```r
aggregate_table <- function(list_of_urls) {

  final_table <- data.frame()

  for (url in list_of_urls) {

    intermediate_table <- extractdata(url)
    final_table <- rbind(final_table, intermediate_table)

  }

  return(final_table)

}

required = aggregate_table(urls)
```

You can also explore lapply, which should be faster.

```r
library(data.table)
table_list = lapply(urls, extractdata)
required  = rbindlist(table_list)
```

Comment: this one works amazing. Even with larger datasets, the data is extracted within no time. Thank you.:) Love u StackOerflow